# Netty Server BindException

Tags: exception, servlets, bind, netty

I am writing a netty server in a servlet. Every time the servlet get initialized by the container, it starts the netty server. But I always get the bind exception saying that "address already in use: bind". The exception I got is like below.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bindAddress already in use: bind

at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:101)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:474)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadHandler.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:995)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind0(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:488)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:474)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.bind(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:837)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:193)
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:321)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:354)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:366)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So, is there some one can help get out of this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's already running, or something else is, on the same port.

Comment: How are you starting and stopping netty? Unless you already have something else using that port, this is caused by trying to run your netty server twice.

Answer (score 2):

Something is already running on the same port. Use "netstat -tuplen" or "lsof -i | grep LISTEN" to find out which process it is.